# AWS Event-bridge to invoke an ECS Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge

I want an ECS task to be invoked when a user an upload a file to a bucket of choice (the task is to unzip a file). I have managed to sort out pretty much every thing but cannot figure out how to pass the event detail across to ECS to process.

I’ve looked in the docs for specific guidance around this but cannot find anything around this.

I have seen suggestions using InputTransformations that get passed on to containerOverrides in the ECS container. But I cannot find anywhere to do that on the UI (when the target is ECS Task) and when i did that via CDK, nothing happens!

Has anyone managed to get this working? (Suitable alternatives are welcome too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [the list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/pipes-reference/API_EcsContainerOverride.html) of things you can override on the ECS task when invoking from EventBridge. Further documented in [the ECS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerOverride.html). To pass in the S3 object event source, you would either need to override the `Command` parameter to pass the S3 object key as a parameter to the command, or modify the `Environment` to include an environment variable with the S3 object key. I suggest using the `Environment` method, and then modifying your code to check that environment variable for the S3 key.

The format of the Object Created event S3 will send to EventBridge is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ev-events.html).

[The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html) describes how to do this in the AWS Console UI. You would create an Input Transform like the following:

```
  {
    containerOverrides = [
      {
        name = "name-of-container-to-override",
        environment = [
          {name: 'S3_BUCKET', value: "$.detail.bucket.name"},
          {name: 'S3_OBJECT_KEY', value: "$.detail.object.key"},
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for all the pointers. I chose the env. variables as the best way to go about it too. However i'm still not seeing a way to configure input transformation via UI or CDK when ECS Task selected as the target (us-east-1).

I can see the option to 'Configure target input' under Additional settings for the other target types but not ECS Task. I really hope im missing something really obvious here.

Comment: Sorry I don't use the UI, but I know it is possible to do with an ECS task target, because I can do this same thing with Terraform. Also, if you look at the EventBridge Pipes documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/pipes-reference/Welcome.html it list ECS container overrides as something you can do https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/pipes-reference/API_EcsContainerOverride.html You might try the EventBridge Pipes section in the UI.